# MIL SIL equivalence testing with Matlab Simulink in process advisor app

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am currently working on a built-in example from Matlab 2022b.

> > processAdvisorExampleStart

I performed MIL with the built-in task TestPerTestCase.m and SIL test execution with modified TestPerTestCase.m (as simulation mode is not supported for 22b).

I have stored the results in two different folders, MIL_test and SIL_test. Each folder contains 3 test results.

I want to use a built-in query or modified built-in query to import this result on an iteration basis so that when the first result from the MIL_test folder is imported, the first result from the SIL_test folder is also imported.

I have figured out how to perform an equivalence test after importing the result.

Do you have any idea how to perform this?

I have tried using the built-in query GetOutputofDependentTask, but cannot iterate for 3 results. All results come in one go.